# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc, cross-domain

I'm using SpringMVC.I want to call an XML file with web service in order to parse it later.The problem is that I can't access the XML file, I have got this error:No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.I have tried the solution below:

I created a new class which purpose is to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header on the requested ressource.This is the class

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class JsonpFilter implements Filter {

private String functionName;

@Override
public void destroy() {

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse servletResponse,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    if (!(request instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
        throw new ServletException("This filter can "
                                   + " only process HttpServletRequest requests");
    }

    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

    if (isJSONPRequest(httpRequest)) {
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        out.println(getCallbackMethod(httpRequest) + "(");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        out.println(");");

        response.setContentType("text/javascript");
    } else {
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    this.functionName = filterConfig.getInitParameter("encoding");
    if(this.functionName == null || this.functionName.length() <= 0) {
        this.functionName = "callback";
    }
}

private String getCallbackMethod(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
    return httpRequest.getParameter(this.functionName);
}

private boolean isJSONPRequest(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
    String callbackMethod = getCallbackMethod(httpRequest);
    return (callbackMethod != null && callbackMethod.length() > 0);
}
```

}

then I add the these two lines in my web.xml file:

```
    <display-name>DataServices</display-name>

   <filter>
    <filter-name>JSONPRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class> com.mycompany.myapp.JsonpFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>functionName</param-name>
        <param-value>callback</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>JSONPRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I don't have any complilation problem, but I still have the same error in the console at the execution time.So, the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header isn't taken into account.
Please,If you can find out what is wrong with my program, or suggest me another solution, I will be thankful

Answer (score 1):

To do this implement this interface

> org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor

here is an example

```
@Component
public class CORSInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor{
   private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(CORSInterceptor.class);

   @Override
   public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

       LOG.trace("sending headers");
       response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
       response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE");
       response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
       response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");

       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView)
        throws Exception {

   }

   @Override
   public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
        throws Exception {
        LOG.trace("afterCompletion is called");
   }

}
```

Then add this line to your application context

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.elm.mb.rest.interceptors.CORSInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```